# how to update data multiple database and single instance in postgresql using php

Tags: php, postgresql

```
<?php
$linecount = 1;  
$file_handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");  
while(!feof($file_handle)) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode(' ', trim($line_of_text)) or die ("cant divid array");  
$dbname = $parts[0];
$GRPCODE = $parts[1];
$TICKETNO = $parts[2];

print "".$linecount.". DATABASE NAME: " .$dbname." GROUP CODE: ". $GRPCODE. " TICKET NO: ". $TICKETNO."<BR\>";

$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=$dbname user=postgres password=asa@123") or die("not connected");

// fetch the data
$rows = pg_query($db,'UPDATE TABSUBSMST SET INTIMATION=\'N\' WHERE GRPCODE=\'$GRPCODE\' 
AND coalesce(ticketno::numeric::text)=\'$ticketno\'
') or die("problem with query") ;


if(!$rows){print ("Please check! Query NOT updated! ");}
else
    {print ("Query updated ");}


pg_close($db) or die("cant close the db");

$linecount++;
}

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

**Php and Postgre-sql**

I need to update table in my database [many database with one instance]. but input values taking from text file.

not showing no error in this program.  but not updating any row in the database.
Kindly correct the program.

**I think problem with connecting to database**.

input.txt

```
AMBUR AM40403 34
AMBUR AM90401 12
AMBUR AM70401 27
AMBUR AM40401 17
AMBUR AM70401 4
AMBUR AM70401 5
```

**output is**
~1. DATABASE NAME: AMBUR GROUP CODE: AM40403 TICKET NO: 34AMBUR~
~current database name : Resource id #5~
~0 rows affected ~
~Query updated~

Comment: Perhaps the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` query matches no rows?  When you debug, what is the actual text of the query being executed?  When you execute that query manually, what are the results?

Comment: the output is  <br>

Comment: 1. DATABASE NAME: AMBUR GROUP CODE: AM40403 TICKET NO: 34AMBUR  
<NEWLINE>current database name : Resource id #5  
<NEWLINE>0 rows affected  
<NEWLINE>Query updated

Comment: Take note of the output... `"0 rows affected"`.  Your `WHERE` clause matches no records.  So there's nothing to update.  What exactly is the problem or is unclear about that result?

Comment: problem is dbname taking place only

Comment: if u giving manually dbname is working fine